# decentralization in ASP.Net not using Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an asp.net project. There are 2 folders in my project: Admin and Normal_User.
I want to do like this:
-when an user Login to my page, if he's admin, he can only access file in Admin folder, if he's  a normal user, he can only access file in Normal_User folder.

How can I do this without using Session.
because if I use Session, i have to check Session in every .aspx file to allow user access that file, so I don't want to use this.

Comment: You should probably read on build in authentication and authorization in ASP.NET

Comment: are you working with visual studio 2010?

Comment: I'm working with VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can use role provider by microsoft and define the roles and display the content based on the user's role http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx